# how to use a word from random list to generate another random list

Tags: python

i am try to get some a random word in the list and when i get the random word in the list i create another random list based on the result of first i tried some code and got this
program:

```
x = "ph"
y = "ch"
z = "ma"
import random 
p = [x, y, z]
print(random.choice(p))

if p==x:
    a = "cl"
    b = "el"
    c = "mo"
    import random
    q = [a, b, c]
    print(random.choice(q))
if p==y:
    d = "phy"
    e = "ino"
    f = "org"
    import random 
    r = [d, e, f]
    print(random.choice(r))
if p==z:
    g ="al"
    h = "con"
    i = "int"
    import random 
    s = [g, h, i]
    print(random.choice(s))
```

this code only pick the word from p
how to get the walue for q,r,s

Comment: `p` will always be the first `list` of values `x, y, z`, so it won't ever be equal to just one of them. Also, you don't need to import random all the time, just once is good enough

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "ph"
y = "ch"
z = "ma"
import random 
p = [x, y, z]
randomChoice = random.choice(p)
print(randomChoice)

if randomChoice==x:
    a = "cl"
    b = "el"
    c = "mo"
    q = [a, b, c]
    print(random.choice(q))
if randomChoice==y:
    d = "phy"
    e = "ino"
    f = "org"
    r = [d, e, f]
    print(random.choice(r))
if randomChoice==z:
    g ="al"
    h = "con"
    i = "int"
    s = [g, h, i]
    print(random.choice(s))
```

The point was to save the result of `random.choice(p)` before printing it out. Then use that saved value in conditional statements.